# How to Sum data in a DatagridView with Condition from another Column in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want help for some code to sum VOLUME with condition from another Column from a dataGridView and the total sum will be put in the specific Value Range TextBox.

For Example:

It looks like this:

Value Range for diameter :

textbox1 = 0.26 - 0.29

textbox2 = 0.30 - 0.39

LENGTH | DIAMETER | VOLUME

2.8  |   0.26   |  0.14

2.7  |   0.27   |  0.15

2.9  |   0.31   |  0.21

textbox 1 = 0.29

textbox 2 = 0.21

So what happened is it will sum up VOLUME if DIAMETER fits the Value Range.

Here's the Sample Image:

[image: Screenshot of Actual Form]

Comment: How are you loading the data in the gridview?

Comment: Just by typing the data inside the datagridview and save it to database after

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya any suggestions?

Comment: Where are `textbox1` and `textbox2` in the Form?

Comment: Just refer to the cells and calculate the result. What's the problem? Why you are not referring the cells using `dataGridView[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value` or using the data source values behind the control?